# perl + create loop to print values from INI file

Tags: perl

My name is abbi

My first perl script run on linux machine

This script read the INI file called (input) and print the values of val , param , name .....

How to create loop that print values of val1-valn OR loop to print values of param1-paramn... etc? (in place the print command's in the script )

- the loop must have option to match the parameter
  for example print only param1 until paramn values

n - Is the last number of each param

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl




 open(IN,"input") or die "Couldn't open input: $!\n"; 
 while(<IN>) { 
 chomp; 
 /^([^=]+)=(.*)$/; 
 $config{$1} = $2; 

 } 
 close(IN);


 print $config{val1};
 print $config{val2};
 print $config{val3};

 print $config{param1};
 print $config{param2};
 print $config{param3}; 

 print $config{name1};
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

example of the  ini file from linux machine

cat input

```
  val1=1
  val2=2
  val3=3
  param1=a
  param2=b
  param3=c
  name1=abbi
  name2=diana
  name3=elena
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your last comment, this will do what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %config;
my $max_n = 0;
my $input = 'input';
open my $in, '<', $input
    or die "unable to open '$input' for reading: $!";
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^(.*?(\d+))\s*=(.*)$/) { 
        $config{$1} = $3; 
        $max_n = $2 if $2 > $max_n;
    }
}
close $in or die "unable to close '$input': $!";

for my $n(1..$max_n) {
    for my $param (qw/val param/) {
        print "$param.$n = $config{$param.$n}\n" if exists $config{$param.$n};
    }
}
```

Comment: hi M42 the same question for you:, can I set argument in place param for example in place param I set $param , and $param can be any word ?? abbi –

Comment: another question what need to change in your script in order to
print first together val1 & param1 and then on the second loop val2 & param2 and so on .....,
abbi

Comment: hi M42 see I get ERROR


Global symbol "$max_n" requires explicit package name at ./new_ini line 22.

Comment: Did you really copy paste the code ? I think you forgot my $max_n on the 5th line.

Comment: No the copy is OK (the $max_n) in the line I am sure about this
-:(
abbi

Comment: This message is typicaly of a non-declaration. May be you put this declaration inside another bloc of code ?

Comment: sorry my fault I forget the my $max_n = 0;
its seems OK I now check it with some parameters please wait

Comment: Please forgive me 
But its not exactly what I want
Can you change the print syntax in order to print the val & param in the same print command (to print both parameters values?)

Comment: I edited the answer. But you could find it by yourself. please upvote this answer if it is usefull !!

Comment: No, but you can increase the number on the top left of the answer. Not just to get some more points, but to show to ones who search for an answer to a similar question retrieve it more easily.

Comment: I see but I need the open ID this aprocedure that I need to perfrom?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) to read your .ini file.
Then you can use the returned hash to filter what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my %config;

open my $input, "<", "input"
    or die "Couldn't open input: $!\n"; 
while(<$input>) { 
    chomp; 
    if ( /^([^=]+)=(.*)$/) { 
        $config{$1} = $2; 
    }
} 
close($input) or die $!;

for (sort keys %config) {
    if (/param\d+/) {
        print "$config{$_}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Kinopiko , can I set argument in place param
for example in place param I set $param , and $param can be any word ??
abbi

Comment: little problem for example if param1A its also match it , in case of param<number> have some char on the right side as param1X then its must not match it , the rule must as for example param<NUMBER> how to solve this problem?

Comment: @abbi: use a $ at the end of the regular expression.

Comment: another question what need to change in your script in order to
print first together val1 & param1 and then on the second loop val2 & param2 and so on .....,
abbi

Comment: @abbi: could you try to do that yourself as an exercise?

Comment: I try but I not sure what I need to do -:( ?

Comment: I make some tests in your script to print together the val1 & param1 & name1 and on the second loop val1 & param2 & name2 
but I not succeeded -:( 
abbi

Comment: OK, well ask as another question, giving the script. Don't forget to accept an answer for this question too.

Comment: OK I accept your solution , And I will ask anew question soon abbi